# Is it good practice to use getters in a view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, domain-driven-design, getter-setter

I have two tables: Campaigns, Campaign_statistics. I need to output campaigns list with nested statistics.

To start, I just had a method in model which created an array like the following:

```
array(
    'id', // integer
    'campaign_name',// string
    'stats'// nested array of arrays with stats by periods
);
```

In a view I had two foreach loops (one nested inside another):

```
<? foreach ($this->campaigns as $campaign): ?>
    <div class="campaign">
        <?= $campaign['name'] ?>
        <? foreach($campaign['stats'] as $monthStats): ?>
            <div class="statistics">
                <?= $monthStats['views'] ?>
            </div>
        <? endforeach ?>
    </div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

That implementation of a model results in messy code, so I decided to try to make Campaign an object. In a view I make use of getters:

```
<? foreach($this->campaigns as $campaign): ?>
    <div class="campaign">
    <?= $campaign->getName() ?>
    <? foreach($campaign->getMonthStats() as $monthStats): ?>
        <div class="statistics">
            <?= $monthStats->getViews() ?>
        </div>
    <? endforeach ?>
    </div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

I've never seen any framework uses getters like this. What are pros/cons of this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beauty with getters in object oriented design is that they hide the complexity of how the returned result is computed. So you can change the way you are computing the views and its automatically updated across all applications.

Purists claim that you should not have method calls in views etc, but pragmatists like myself say, put method calls in views since methods can be unit tested. However when you find that the outputs are becoming too complex (Martin Fowler calls this objects becoming too intimate with each other), then you need to refactor to use a single method call.

Bottom line: Methods good because their outputs can be verified

Answer (score 1):

I've had same argument with my colleagues previously and I disagree with using methods inside template. This makes templates not transparent, there is no clear knowledge of what is available inside template - you must know objects that you deal with and designers, nor developers who join later shouldn't worry about that, they should see of whats getting passed in controller and thats it. Not to mention that method calls from inside of a template may change data that was already passed inside.. And although I know that in some cases its ok for template to have changes in cycle or something, I tend to think that template is more static then the rest of code - iterating over an array will not change any other array. But i'm not so certain with objects.

It also adds extra dependency for refactoring.

And it also adds complexity and seduction for developers to start calling SQLs or doing heavy-logic inside a template.

I probably could also point out that simple template engines tend to be a simple text-replacers. And methods is not an option for them.

Comment: We're speaking about getters, not big methods :) I agree with you for anything more complex than getters

Comment: right. well i'm just scared of colons :D I suppose if you know what you are doing, its ok to meddle with uranium too.

Answer (score 1):

usually you won't see explicit getters you'll see people access the properties.
 However this will only work if you properties are public.
 Implementing Zend_Form in the view you can access the elements and other attributes using getters and setters. 
I don't see any major issue with the choice you have made.
 I however may have implemented the second foreach() using the [partialLoop()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) view helper or possiblly built my own view helper particularly if this was something I intended to use in more then one place.

```
//example of what is commonly seen...
<? foreach($this->campaigns as $campaign): ?>
    <div class="campaign">
    <?= $campaign->name ?>
    <? foreach($campaign->stats as $monthStats): ?>
        <div class="statistics">
            <?= $monthStats->views() ?>
        </div>
    <? endforeach ?>
    </div>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Just my opinion, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds OK to me :)
Magento allow the same thing for instance.

Anyway, it's more a matter of personal view than anything... But I tend to agree with you, it makes the model or controller easier to read (no need for $view->toto = $model->getToto()